# is my newly setup mail server on my laptop hacked?

Tags: postfix, malware

I have just installed `postfix` on Arch Linux. I am following [Arch wiki to set aliases](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Postfix#Aliases) to set following line in `/etc/postfix/aliases`

```
root: edward
```

after this I ran `postalias /etc/postfix/aliases`  and got this error:

```
edward@ArchLinux ~ : postalias /etc/postfix/aliases
postalias: fatal: parameter inet_interfaces: no local interface found for 218.93.250.18
```

Here's my `inet_interfaces` definition from the postfix configuration file:

```
inet_interfaces = $myhostname, localhost
```

[After looking up about `218.93.250.18` on web](http://whois.domaintools.com/218.93.250.18) I found out that it is a Chinese IP address:

```
IP Information for 218.93.250.18
Quick Stats
IP Location     China China Nanjing Chinanet Jiangsu Province Network
ASN     China AS4134 CHINANET-BACKBONE No.31,Jin-rong Street, CN (registered Aug 01, 2002)
Whois Server    whois.apnic.net
IP Address  218.93.250.18
Reverse IP  2 websites use this address.
```

Am I being hacked? from where does this Chinese address came about which I don't know anything...

Comment: It might be helpful to include the relevant contents of your postfix configuration...

Comment: @roaima I have only changed contents of main.cf copy of which is [here](http://sprunge.us/hcXG
)

Comment: @roaima when I had this problem, I had `myhostname = localhost` commented out in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file, on removing `#` this problem dissappeared

Comment: So you're saying the problem is now fixed? Or that I've put incorrect information into your Question? If so, please [edit] it to get it right, and don't feed us wrong information in your responses.

Comment: @roaima those two lines you added are fine and correct

Comment: please post the output of 'ifconfig', and the contents of /etc/hosts and /etc/nsswitch.conf

Comment: @gerhardd.  output of `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is here http://sprunge.us/DfXe output of `ifconfig` is here http://sprunge.us/NYcM

Comment: do you have anything in ' /var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf' ?

Comment: @gerhardd. there is not such file :(

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and comment out `inet_interfaces = all`

To get more information about IP adress (Phone number , mail , fax ...) , open the terminal and type the following command:

```
whois 218.93.250.18
```

you can see [218.93.250.18 Scan Report](http://www.ipvoid.com/scan/218.93.250.18/) ; it is not vulnerable.

Comment: I know how to lookup about IP address but I don't know how this helps me